# Do I need put " python" infront for the .py if write a crontab for it?

Tags: python, cron

Do I need put " python" infront for the .py if write a crontab for it?
This is how I do it - `*/10 * * * * /home/TwitterFollowBot/python bot.py`
is this correct? and I need to run it every 10 minutes. And will it work even after closing the terminal?

Nov 26 07:12:01 ip************* CRON[3180]: (root) CMD (python  /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py)
Nov 26 07:13:01 ip************* CRON[3190]: (root) CMD (python  /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py)
Nov 26 07:14:01 ip************* CRON[3195]: (root) CMD (python  /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py)
Nov 26 07:15:01 ip************* CRON[3211]: (root) CMD (python  /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py)
Nov 26 07:16:01 ip************* CRON[3226]: (root) CMD (python  /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py)
Nov 26 07:17:01 ip************* CRON[3243]: (root) CMD (python  /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py)
Nov 26 07:17:01 ip************* CRON[3244]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov 26 07:18:01 ip************* CRON[3275]: (root) CMD (python /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py)
Nov 26 07:19:01 ip************* CRON[3278]: (root) CMD (python /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py)
Nov 26 07:20:01 ip************* CRON[3282]: (root) CMD (python /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py)

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crontab wont run python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337149/crontab-wont-run-python-script)

Answer (score 1):

### How to execute a python file without calling "python" directly

If you want to execute a python file directly set the file to executable (e.g. use `chmod +x bot.py`) and add a shebang on the first line of `bot.py` that looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then you can execute the python file directly by calling `/home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.

### The (likely) cause of the error

I am guessing your error might be because you are trying to execute a python that does not exist.  You have:

```
/home/TwitterFollowBot/python bot.py
```

Your command it trying to execute a python binary in the `/home/TwitterFollowBot` directory which probably doesn't exist (unless you installed python there).  Maybe you mean to execute:

```
python /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py
```

This will execute the `python` found on the path with the absolute path to your python file as its argument.

Comment: so let me get cleared, all I have to do is add ( #!/usr/bin/env python ) top of the bot.py and make the crontab like this?
 */10 * * * * /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py

and one more thing,
is this the correct way to restart it every 10 minutes? 
*/10 * * * * /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py

Comment: Yes, the shebang (#!) describes how the program should be run `/usr/bin/env python` will find the python installed on the system and run it.  */10 looks correct to run every 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One last thing, as you mentioned above do i have to put "python" before "/home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py" ? like this "python /home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py" or just "/home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py"

Comment: If you added the correct shebang and made it executable correctly (test by just running the script on the command line as "/home/TwitterFollowBot/bot.py", then you don't need the "python" before it in the crontab either.

Comment: I tried it like you said but still it's not working :(

Comment: Have you had a look in your cron log file to see what happens when it tries to start?